# Computing time period $T=l \sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t \int_{0 }^{1} ds(1-s^{\frac{1 } {t}})^{-\frac{1 } {2 }} $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, beta-function

Given:

$T=l \sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t \int_{0 }^{1} ds(1-s^{\frac{1 } {t}})^{-\frac{1 } {2 }} $

$l,t, V_0>0$.

Need to calculate the time period $(T)$ when $t \to 0$

So I tried to solve by two different ways but got different solutions.
Which one is the correct and why?

**first way:**

$\lim_{t\to 0} l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t \int_{0 }^{1} ds(1-s^{\frac{1 } {t}})^{-\frac{1 } {2 }} $

$= l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}} \lim_{t\to 0} \int_{0 }^{1} ds(-s^{-\frac{1 } {2t}})=-l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E} } \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1} {1-\frac{1}{2t}} s^{1-\frac{1 } {2 t} } \big|_0^1=0$

**second way:**

$ l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t \int_{0 }^{1} ds(1-s^{\frac{1 } {t}})^{-\frac{1 } {2 }}=l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} ) \int_{0 }^{1} dk(1-k) ^{-\frac{1 } {2}}tk^{t-1}=l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t t \beta (t, 0.5)$

The substitution I did: $k=s^{\frac{1 } {t} } $

Eventually I got :

$\lim_{t\to 0} l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}(\frac{E} {V_0} )^t t \beta (t, 0.5)=l\sqrt{\frac{2m} {E}}$

So as you see I got 2 different answers.

Would appreciate for your insights.

Thank you

Comment: The second way is quite straightforward but the first way is so wrong I can't see what you were trying to do. How did you start out with a positive integral and make it negative, for example? As $t\rightarrow0$, $s^{1/t}\rightarrow0$ exponentially so you could cook up a proof that the integrand was effectively $(1-0)^{-1/2}=1$ if the second method weren't already so easy.

Comment: So the second way is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could just state that the second method is correct, but when you call yourself @user5713492 you are hardly claiming to be the voice of authority, so let's see how we could actually make the first method fly by estimating the value of the integral. Choose any $0<\epsilon\le1/2$ and let
$$I(t)=\int_0^1\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds=\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds+\int_{1-\epsilon^2/16}^1\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}I_1&=\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds=\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}1ds+\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\left[\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}-1\right]ds\\
&=1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}+\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\frac{1-\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{1/2}}{\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{1/2}}ds\\
&=1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}+\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\frac{s^{1/t}}{\left(1+\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{1/2}\right)\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{1/2}}ds\end{align}$$
If we constrain
$$0<t<\frac{\ln(1-\epsilon^2/16)}{\ln(\epsilon/2)}$$
Then since $0\le s\le1-\epsilon^2/16<1$,
$$0\le s^{1/t}\le(1-\epsilon^2/16)^{1/t}\le e^{\frac{\ln(\epsilon/2)}{\ln(1-\epsilon^2/16)}\ln(1-\epsilon^2/16)}=\frac{\epsilon}2<\frac12$$
So we can say that $0<\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{1/2}<\left(1-\frac12\right)^{1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ so
$$1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}<I_1<1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}+\int_0^{1-\epsilon^2/16}\frac{\frac{\epsilon}2}{\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\frac1{\sqrt2}}ds<1+\frac{\epsilon}2$$
If $t<1$ then if $1-\epsilon^2/16\le s\le1$, $0<s^{1/t}\le s\le1$ so $0\le1-s\le1-s^{1/t}<1$ and
$$\begin{align}\int_{1-\epsilon^2/16}^11ds&=\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}\\
&<I_2=\int_{1-\epsilon^2/16}^1\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds\\
&\le\int_{1-\epsilon^2/16}^1(1-s)^{-1/2}ds=\left.-2(1-s)^{1/2}\right|_{1-\epsilon^2/16}^1=\frac{\epsilon}2\end{align}$$
Adding up, we have
$$1=1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{16}<I(t)=I_1+I_2<1+\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2=1+\epsilon$$
That is to say
$$\left|\int_0^1\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds-1\right|<\epsilon$$
Provided
$$0<t<\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\ln\left(1-\epsilon^2/16\right)}{\ln(\epsilon/2)}\right)$$
And that completes our $\epsilon,\delta$ proof that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\int_0^1\left(1-s^{1/t}\right)^{-1/2}ds=1$$

Comment: That's very detailed. Thank you! So it can be done by estimation only, not by direct computation?

Comment: Yes, that's what you seemed to be doing in your first method, but you had $3$ issues: first $1-s^{1/t}\approx1$, not $-s^{1/t}$. Second, $(-s^{1/t})^{-1/2}\ne-\left((s^{1/t})^{-1/2}\right)$, and third $(s^{1/t})^{-1/2}\ne s^{\frac1{2t}}$. It would have probably been easier to write up a lecture on the Gamma and Beta functions so that one could apply the second method rather than do the estimation, but sometimes estimation is all you've got so I wanted to show how it worked in this problem.

Comment: The third mistake you have mentioned is just a typo, you can see that the integration I did is with the minus on the power. But I understand the other mistakes. You estimation is very helpful tho I still thinks we can do it directly. Maybe I'm wrong.